# How to secure KDB/Q web interface

Tags: kdb

I am aware of the fact that we can run a Q process with the `-p` parameter which enables other instances to connect to it and enables also a web interface on that port.

Is there a way how to secure the connection so there will be some kind of authorization? In the moment I don't like the fact that anyone can view and even execute queries on my database when it is running with the `-p` parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add authentication by using [`-U`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/cmdline/#-u-usr-pwd):

```
-U /path/to/password.txt
```

This file contains *user:password* where password is result of in q `md5"password"` and strip off `0x` in front.

Comment: Thanks for this one. How does this work if I have the Q script connecting to the remote box which will be secured?

Comment: h:hopen `:host:port:username:password

Comment: h"select from price where sym=`MSFT"

Answer (score 4):

there's also the [`.z.pw`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotz/#zpw-validate-user) and [`.z.ac`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotz/#zac-http-auth-from-cookie) hooks, which can be used for more complex auth logic